# Drying up Models for Solr Sunspot searchable with Concerns

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, search, model, sunspot-solr

I want to dry up my models; but Sunspot only allows one(1) "searchable" block in a model. making 2 just ignores the second one. Failed Example below:

**digital.rb**

```
class Digital < ActiveRecord::Base

  include BaseConcerns

  belongs_to :digitable, polymorphic: true

  # IGNORES THIS
  searchable do

    string :url
    text :url

    string :remark
    text :remark

  end

end
```

**base_concerns.rb**

```
module BaseConcerns extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_create{
      self.id = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.downcase if id.blank?
    }
    self.primary_key = 'id'

    # DOES THIS
    searchable do
      text :id
      time :created_at
      time :updated_at
    end

  end

end
```

I want to DRY up my models using some concern and want some similarly named columns to be searchable; while others I can just specify; how can I do this?